# Users have to sign in every time?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

Right now, our users sign in every time they want to chat with our bot. It can be very annoying for them. Here's some information about the bot:

- The bot is accessed using the Direct Line channel.
- When I use the "Test in Web Chat" feature in Azure, I stay signed in every time. So it works fine there.
- We are using the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/README.md#bot-framework-web-chat) component for the UI.
- I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/25/enhanced-direct-line-authentication-features/) to generate a user token. I generated a user ID like this:

  - `var userId = "dl_" + new Random().Next() + new DateTime().Ticks;`

Here is the code to authenticate users:

```
public GreetingDialog(IConfiguration configuration, IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    : base(INTENTS.GREETING, configuration["ConnectionName"])
{
    TelemetryClient = telemetryClient;

    AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
        nameof(OAuthPrompt),
        new OAuthPromptSettings
        {
            ConnectionName = ConnectionName,
            Text = " Welcome! Please Sign In.",
            Title = "Sign In",
            Timeout = 30000,
        })
    {
        TelemetryClient = telemetryClient
    });

    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(INTENTS.GREETING, new WaterfallStep[] {
        PromptStepAsync,
        GreetStepAsync,
        })
    {
        TelemetryClient = telemetryClient
    });
    InitialDialogId = INTENTS.GREETING;
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> GreetStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext step, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Dies the user id change when a new session starts?

Comment: Yes. This is what's in Microsoft's tutorial that I linked. I don't know why they did this. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time you generate a user Id randomly, a new conversation is created. Being a new conversation, the bot cannot find the previous session.

If you want to do a test you can assign a static ID user:

`var userId = "dl_123456789";`

It shouldn't ask you to log in again.

To make a complete solution, the `userId` should be tied to some distinctive credentials in your application (ex: username/password)

Comment: This sounds like the correct solution. Why did Microsoft post an example where the user ID was literally a GUID generated on the server side? They posted it here: https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/25/enhanced-direct-line-authentication-features/

Comment: It was only for demonstration purposes. Even though is true that they have to leave that clear.

If you want to have some way to distinct users without built an authentication process in your app, you could store the generated DirectLine token in the Localstorage of the client-side and every time you try to get the token, check the local storage first to see if it has one already and then use it.  (If it help you out, mark it as correct :))

Comment: ^ Yes. That's the solution I implemented. Thank you.